# How to paste image from clipboard into PyQT5 Document?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qt5

I'm a noob PyQt5 user following [a tutorial](https://www.learnpyqt.com/examples/megasolid-idiom-rich-text-editor/) and I'm confused how I might extend the sample code below.

The two handlers `canInsertFromMimeData` and `insertFromMimeData` Qt5 methods accept an image mime datatype dragged and dropped onto `document` (that works great). They both receive a signal parameter source which receives a QMimeData object.

However, If I try to **paste** an image copied from the Windows clipboard into the document it just crashes as there is no handler for this.

Searching the Qt5 documentation at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmimedata.html just leads me to further confusion as I'm not a C++ programmer and I'm using Python 3.x and PyQt5 to do this.

**How would I write a handler to allow an image copied to the clipboard to be pasted into the document directly?**

```
    class TextEdit(QTextEdit):

    def canInsertFromMimeData(self, source):

        if source.hasImage():
            return True
        else:
            return super(TextEdit, self).canInsertFromMimeData(source)

    def insertFromMimeData(self, source):

        cursor = self.textCursor()
        document = self.document()

        if source.hasUrls():

            for u in source.urls():
                file_ext = splitext(str(u.toLocalFile()))
                if u.isLocalFile() and file_ext in IMAGE_EXTENSIONS:
                    image = QImage(u.toLocalFile())
                    document.addResource(QTextDocument.ImageResource, u, image)
                    cursor.insertImage(u.toLocalFile())

                else:
                    # If we hit a non-image or non-local URL break the loop and fall out
                    # to the super call & let Qt handle it
                    break

            else:
                # If all were valid images, finish here.
                return


        elif source.hasImage():
            image = source.imageData()
            uuid = hexuuid()
            document.addResource(QTextDocument.ImageResource, uuid, image)
            cursor.insertImage(uuid)
            return

        super(TextEdit, self).insertFromMimeData(source)
```

code source: https://www.learnpyqt.com/examples/megasolid-idiom-rich-text-editor/

Answer (score 0):

I was exactly in the same position as you. I am also new to Python, so there might be mistakes.

The variable uuid in document.addResource(QTextDocument.ImageResource, uuid, image) is not working. It should be a path -> QUrl(uuid).
Now you can insert the image. However, because the path to an image from the clipboard is changing, it would be better to use a different path, for example to the directory where you are also saving the files.

Also be aware that the user has to select the file type when saving (.html)

For my own project I am going to print the file as pdf. That way you dont have to worry about paths to images ^-^

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by converting to base64 inline embedding of the images, then no resource files as it is all in one file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).